# jquery toggle between divs and subsequently hide active div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, hidden

a play on a similar question asked by me that was graciously answered.

three divs, all hidden. jquery toggles between them via different links. this works great! now, i'd like to clink the link corresponding to the active div and hide it, esentially the same as when the page loads with all of them hidden. right now it fades out and back in.

help! thank you!

HTML:

```
 <div id="nav">
    <a class="home" id="show_about" title="About">ABOUT</a><br />
    <a class="home" id="show_subscribe" title="Subscribe">SUBSCRIBE</a><br />
    <a class="home" id="show_contact" title="Contact">CONTACT</a>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
    <div class="current" id="about">
        <p>ABOUT's content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="subscribe">
        <p>SUBSCRIBE's content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <p>CONTACT's content</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#about').css('display', 'none');
        $('#subscribe').css('display', 'none');
        $('#contact').css('display', 'none');
    });
    $('.home').click(function(){   
        var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function(){
            $('#'+id).fadeIn(600);
            $('.current').removeClass('current');
            $('#'+id).addClass('current');     
        });   
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out..

Since on fadeOut the current class is removed, if the size of current is 0 it means nothing is selected.  We can simply fadeIn the content div.

```
$('#about, #subscribe, #contact').hide();

$('.home').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    }
    else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function(){showContent($content)});
    }
});

function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/CZXqz/).

Comment: @Mark
I think I should add in a little floating X button to close the window. Best to work that feature into this function, or another altogether?
#close is the ID

Comment: So you want to add a close link in the content div?  I would work it into a different function.  Since right now the home click is handling your menu/content display.  If you work in a close function it could result in a method that might be doing to much.

Comment: @Mark great, thank you for the direction. if i understand your function correctly.. it's moving the class="current" to the displayed div. could i then make a simple click function that fades out the class="current" div?

Comment: Yeah that should work for your needs.  Glad I could be of some help.

Comment: @Mark built it into the jsFiddle you sent.. function isn't working based on the class="current". any ideas? sorry to take up all of your time! http://jsfiddle.net/CZXqz/2/

Comment: No worries, the problem was you had multiple ID's of close an ID needs to be unique to the dom.  I adjusted to use a class of close instead and appears to behave correctly.  http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/CZXqz/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
$(function(){
        $('#content div').hide();
    });

    $('.home').click(function(){
        var targetSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('title').toLowerCase();
        var targetShown = $(targetSelector).is(':visible');

        if (targetShown) {
            $(targetSelector).fadeOut(600);
        } else {
            $('#content div:not(' + targetSelector + ')').fadeOut(600,
                                      function() {$(targetSelector).fadeIn(600)});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the id of the clicked element is equal to the id of the element currently being displayed (i.e. the element with the *current* class).  If it is a different element, then a swap needs to take place.  If it is the same element, then it needs to be hidden and have its *current* class removed...

(Edit: fixed code)

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a class="home" id="show_about" title="About">ABOUT</a><br />
    <a class="home" id="show_subscribe" title="Subscribe">SUBSCRIBE</a><br />
    <a class="home" id="show_contact" title="Contact">CONTACT</a>
 </div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
 <div id="content">
    <div id="about">
        <p>ABOUT's content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="subscribe">
        <p>SUBSCRIBE's content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <p>CONTACT's content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="current" id="dummy"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$().ready(function()
{
        $('#about').hide();
        $('#subscribe').hide();
        $('#contact').hide();
        $('#dummy').hide();


  $('.home').click(function() {   
    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();  

      if ($('.current').length >0) {
      if($('.current')[0].id.toLowerCase() != id)
        {
          $('.current').hide();
          $('.current').removeClass('current');
          $('#'+id).addClass('current');     
          $('#'+id).show();
        }
        else
        {
          $('.current').hide();
          $('.current').removeClass('current');
          $('#dummy').addClass('current');
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Just replace the .hide()'s and .shows()'s with fades in and out.

Comment: @Michael , just a suggestion we can use jquery' .hide to hide instead of display none..

Comment: That was copied over from the OP's code and is now removed because it wasn't part of the function that needed adjustment in order to solve the problem.  Valid point, though.

Comment: Important update, Daniel.  Since your div id's are not lcase, and your id variable is, they will never match.  Change the if statement to this: `if ($('.current').id.toLowerCase() != id)`

Comment: @Michael
Made a jsFiddle of your code. It toggles between them correctly, but still fades out then back in instead of just the fade out. http://jsfiddle.net/SHaQe/

Comment: I tested it and borked the code a little. Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CJjMa/2 . Just replace the .hide's and .show's with fade outs and ins.